# svn weird error

Tags: svn

I'm getting an error when i try to commit changes to my project, it's complaining about path not found (on the repository)

```
$ svn ci -m"common CF01ServerProxy"
Sending        src\com\...\TransportClient.java
Adding         src\com\...\app\common\TransportDestination.java
Deleting       src\com\...\app\common\transport\Codec.java
svn: Commit failed (details follow):
svn: '/public/!svn/bc/Common/trunk/src/com//common/transport/serialisers/Serialiser.java' path not found
```

I can't understand how can I fix that

Comment: Are you using any IDE or tool? Did you do anything strange before this started happening? Did anything strange happen before this started happening?

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the svn path, the last line, It has two forward slashes after com:

```
Common/trunk/src/com//common
```

My guess would be that is causing the issue and the path needs to be reset for that repository

Comment: sorry the // is just a copy/paste typo, I was trying to get rid of so many irrelevant directories in my path

Answer (score 0):

Acording to this thread, you aren't pointing correctly to your repository

http://svn.haxx.se/users/archive-2007-06/0600.shtml

http://svn.haxx.se/users/archive-2007-06/0613.shtml

> In the Terminal, you could go into your existing working copy, the one 
>   you use with svnX, and type "svn info", which will show you the 
>   correct URL.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure why SVN behaves this way, the issue was due to the deleted file/directory never actually been created in the repository.

it could be actually an issue with the client (subclipse in this case)

I was inside eclipse, I created a class, and then I add it to svn (without commiting, so nothing went to the repository)
and then I renamed it (so it marks it as a delete and add a different)

and then when I tried to commit, it tried to delete the first instance which was never created... that's my theory

to fix it, I had to revert the directory, and then add the file, and then commit, and then delete it and then commit again..... not ideal